# Message Groups in RabbitMQ / AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

ActiveMQ / JMS has a built in-mechanism for ensuring that messages that share a common header (namely, the JMSXGroupID header) are always consumed by the same consumer of a queue when using a competing consumers pattern.  The consumers of a queue are completely agnostic of the actual header values, as the guarantee of messages with a common header is performed server-side and not consumer-side. For more details on how this works, see http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html .

Is doing such a thing possible with AMQP or with something RabbitMQ specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the time this answer is written, this is not possible with AMQP alone and will require work on the application side of things.  RabbitMQ plans on implementing something like this in the future, but it is not slated for release or development anytime soon.

References: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/262  and https://twitter.com/old_sound/status/410898209788411904

Comment: There is a GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/262

Comment: Edited answer to include that link.  Thanks @Merwan !