# To be sure about concurrency, same group of works in multiple queues (FIFO)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, fifo

I have a question about multi consumer concurrency.
I want to send works to rabbitmq that comes from web request to distributed queues.
I just want to be sure about order of works in multiple queues (FIFO).
Because this request comes from different users eech user requests/works must be ordered.

I have found this feature with different names on Azure ServiceBus and ActiveMQ message grouping.

Is there any way to do this in pretty RabbitMQ ?

I want to quaranty that customer's requests must be ordered each other. 
Each customer may have multiple requests but those requests for that customer must be processed in order.
I desire to process quickly incoming requests with using multiple consumer on different nodes. 
For example different customers 1 to 1000 send requests over 1 millions. 
If I put this huge request in only one queue it takes a lot of time to consume. So I want to share this process load between n (5) node. For customer X 's requests must be in same sequence for processing

Comment: Do you mean ordered or do you mean each user's work items must go to the same consumer even though there are multiple consumers for the queue?  Or both or something else?

Comment: So each customer may have multiple requests but those requests for that customer must be processed  in order but may be out of order (or even interleavedl with those of other customers?  You're talking about what ActiveMQ calls "message grouping"?  (If so edit your question to make it clear: comments can disappear. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ Consistent Hash Exchange Type

We are using RabbitMQ and we have found a plugin. It use **Consistent Hashing** algorithm to distribute messages in order to consistent keys.

For more information about Consistent Hashing ;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viaNG1zyx1g

You can find this plugin from rabbitmq web page

plugin : rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange

https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

When working with event-based systems, and especially when using multiple producers and/or consumers, it is important to come to terms with the fact that there usually is no such thing as a guaranteed order of events. And to get a robust system, it is also wise to design the system so the message handlers are idempotent; they should tolerate to get the same message twice (or more).

There are way to many things that may (and actually should be allowed to) interfere with the order;

- The producers may deliver the messages in a slightly different pace
- One producer might miss an ack (due to a missed package) and will resend the message
- One consumer may get and process a message, but the ack is lost on the way back, so the message is delivered twice (to another consumer).
- Some other service that your handlers depend on might be down, so that you have to reject the message.

That being said, there is one pattern that servicebus-systems like [NServicebus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) use to enforce the order messages are consumed. There are some requirements:

- You *will* need a centralized storage (like a sql-server or document store) that allows for conditional updates; for instance you want to be able to store the sequence number of the last processed message (or how far you have come in the process), but *only* if the already stored sequence/progress is the right/expected one. Storing the user-id and the progress even for millions of customers should be a very easy operation for most databases.
- You make sure the queue is configured with a [dead-letter-queue/exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for retries, and then set your original queue as a dead-letter-queue for that one again.
- You set a TTL (for instance 30 seconds) on the retry/dead-letter-queue. This way the messages that appear on the dead-letter-queue will automatically be pushed back to your original queue after some timeout.
- When processing your messages you check your storage/database if you are in the right state to handle the message (i.e. the needed previous steps are already done).

  - If you are ok to handle it you do and update the storage (conditionally!).
  - If *not* - you nack the message, so that it is thrown on the dead-letter queue. Basically you are saying "nah - I can't handle this message, there are probably some other message in the queue that should be handled first".

This way the happy-path is to process a great number of messages in the right order.
But if something happens and a you get a message out of band, you will throw it on the retry-queue (the dead-letter-queue) and Rabbit will make sure it will get back in the queue to be retried at a later stage. But only after a delay.

The beauty of this is that you are able to handle most of the situations that may interfere with processing the message (out of order messages, dependent services being down, your handler being shut down in the middle of handling the message) in exact the same way; by rejecting the message and letting your infrastructure (Rabbit) take care of it being retried after a while.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming the OP is asking about things like ActiveMQs "message grouping:)

This isn't currently built in to RabbitMQ AFAIK (it wasn't as of 2013 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20671556/751579)) and I'm not aware of it now (though I haven't kept up lately).

However, RabbitMQ's model of exchanges and queues is very flexible - exchanges and queues can be easily created dynamically (this can be done in other messaging systems but, for example, if you read ActiveMQ documentation or Red Hat AMQ documentation you'll find *all* of the examples in the user guides are using pre-declared queues in configuration files loaded at system startup - except for RPC-like request/response communication).

Also it is very easy in RabbitMQ for a consumer (i.e., message consuming thread) to consume from multiple queues.

So you could build, on top of RabbitMQ, a system where you got your desired grouping semantics.

One way would be to create dynamic queues: The first time a customer order was seen or a new group of customer orders a queue would be created with a unique name for all messages for that group - that queue name would be communicated (via another queue) to a consumer who's sole purpose was to load-balance among other consumers that were responsible for handling customer order groups.  I.e., the load-balancer would pull off of its queue a message saying "new group with queue name XYZ" and it would find in a pool of order group consumer a consumer which could take this load and pass it a message saying "start listening to XYZ".

Another way to do it is with pub/sub and topic routing - each customer order group would get a unique topic - and proceed as above.